# Fullcalendar make current date as the start date and do not display previous dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am thinking whether it's possible in the [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to make the start date as the current date and the previous dates should not be displayed.

Here's a graphical image on what I meant.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first day is set using the function [firstDay()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/).
You could set it with [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay(getDay());
    })
});
```

For the button at the top, you could compare the calendar date (using fullCalendar [getDate()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/) ) and the [current date](http://momentjs.com/) (fullCalendar uses MomentJS for the Date handling) and then hide when needed the back button with the fullCalendar [header option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/).

Answer (score 1):

on php

```
$dayOfWeek=date('w');
```

on fullcalendar

```
firstDay:<?php echo $dayOfWeek; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do I disable that back button so that they won't be able to display the past/previous dates? :)